# Determine all real values of $p$ for which the following series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Determine all real values of $p$ for which the following series converges: $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\right)^p$.

I am sort of confused how to solve this. What methods are there to find values of convergence and to prove that a series converges? I know that we could use the integral test and ratio test, but I don't think the integral test would work here since $\sin\left(
\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$ isn't a decreasing function.

Comment: $\sin(1/n)$ behaves very much like $1/n$ when $n$ is large.  And $\sum\frac1{n^p}$ converges exactly when $p>1$.  Use the "limit comparison test".

Answer (score 1):

Hint for some values of p.

For large n, sin(1/n) is approximately 1/n. This simply leads to considreation of: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} n^p\sin^p(1/n)=1$$. So for p>1, the given series converges.

Comment: It should be noted though that $\sin(\dfrac{1}{n}) > 0$ for $n>1$.